# Why did my Visualization tools disappear from the CartoDB Sidebar?

Tags: carto, visualisation

I was working with the "Intensity" visualization tool yesterday.

Using the same data, I created a new map, and now I can only access: Simple, Choropleth, Category, and Bubble.

Where did Intensity, Torque, and the others go?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are now working with polygons, or that there was some glitch in the CartoDB UI.

For polygons, only the wizards that you mention are available, which means that Torque cannot be applied for polygons. You may need to check the geometry types that you have in your table, for example by using:

```
SELECT distinct(ST_GeometryType(the_geom)) FROM tablename
```

The documentation for the [ST_GeometryType PostGIS function is available here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html)